# Mapping possible flags to boolean list efficient method?

Tags: python, list, boolean, mapping

I have a project I'm working on and I wanted to pass possible flags from user input (example "-s") into a boolean list from where I can find specific options the user has requested for.

My code currently:

```
def run():
    running = True
    while running:

        user_input = input()
        dir_path = find_file_name(user_input[2:])
        flags = get_action(dir_path[1])
        file_dump = []

        options = [False] * 6

        if user_input[0] == "Q":
            running = False
            break

        elif user_input[0] == "L":
            options[0] = "-r" in flags
            options[1] = "-f" in flags
            options[2] = "-s" in flags
            options[3] = "-e" in flags
```

While this technique works, I was hoping that there would be a better way to do the last part with the options being set based on the flags contained in the input. I'm also not 100% sure this is a good way to use a `run()` method. Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at standard library `argparse` module. It does what you need and a lot more.

[see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 1):

As jetpack_guy said, `argparse` is the best way to do something like this. This library has a lot of features, but here's how to create booleans from arguments like you need.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-f', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-s', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-e', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.r)
print(args.f)
print(args.s)
print(args.e)
```

`python test.py -r` would produce `r: True, f: False, s: False, e: False`

`python test.py -r -f -s` would produce `r: True, f: True, s: True, e: False`

`python test.py -rsf` would produce `r: True, f: True, s: True, e: False`